# Will buying a new hardware stop my Apple TV+ subscription payment for a year?

Tags: appletv

Apple is offering one year of free Apple TV+ with new hardware purchases at the moment. My question is, when I purchase a new qualified device, will Apple stop charging me for subscription fees for 12 months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will buying a new hardware stop my Apple TV+ subscription payment for a year?

No. If you are already on a paid subscription plan, you don't get a free year of Apple TV+.

The free year offer is only made available to new users, and is available only if you have not availed of a free trial or a paid subscription before.

Comment: I'll take your words for it but do you also have a link?

Comment: @Mohsen I would have included a link to an official document, but this is the kind of thing that should be inferred and a company like Apple generally doesn't put in writing anywhere.

Comment: @Mohsen, From: [https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-plus/](https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-plus/) -- Get 1 year of Apple TV+ free when you buy an Apple device. 1 -- 1. $4.99/month after free trial. One subscription per Family Sharing group. Offer good for 3 months after eligible device activation. Plan automatically renews until cancelled. Restrictions and other terms apply.